# How to check if $\sum_{\ell\in\mathbb{Z^2}} e^{-\vert x-\ell \vert^2}=\sum_{\ell\in\mathbb{Z^2}} e^{-\vert y-\ell \vert^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, integer-lattices

suppose $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ are given such that $\vert x \vert=\vert y \vert$ (where $\vert x \vert$ denote the Euclidean norm). I want to investigate, if the following limits are equal or not:

$$\sum_{\ell\in\mathbb{Z^2}} e^{-\vert x-\ell \vert^2}=\sum_{\ell\in\mathbb{Z^2}} e^{-\vert y-\ell \vert^2}$$

If $y=-x$ then both limits are equal. But what happens, if the angle between $x,y$ is between $0$ and $\pi$? I tried to use $\vert x-\ell\vert^2=\vert x \vert^2 - 2\vert x \vert\vert y \vert\cos(\angle(x,\ell))+ \vert \ell\vert ^2$, but it did not help me.

Can someone tell me how to approach this problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $z=(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$ g(z_1,z_2)=\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}e^{-(x-z_1)^2-(y-z_2)^2}=\sum_{s\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-(s-z_1)^2}\sum_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-(t-z_2)^2}=f(\{z_1\})\cdot f(\{z_2\})$$
where
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-(z-n)^2} = \sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-k^2 \pi^2}e^{-2\pi k i z}=\sqrt{\pi}+2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-k^2\pi^2}\cos(2\pi k z)$$
follows from the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula). In particular $g(z_1,z_2)$ is **always** pretty close to $\pi$, since the coefficients of the last Fourier cosine series decay to zero really fast, and if $(\pm u_1,\pm u_2)$ (for some choice of signs) and $(v_1,v_2)$ are the same element of $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ we have the exact equality $g(u_1,u_2)=g(v_1,v_2)$.

---

**Corollary**:
$$ \frac{1}{4}\left[\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-n^2}+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\right]^2 $$
is an *excellent* approximation of $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have one more question: Do you claim that $g(u_1,u_2)\neq g(v_1,v_2)$  if  $(u_1,u_2)−(v_1,v_2) \notin \mathbb{Z}^2$ ? It is now clear to me that $g(u_1,u_2) = g(v_1,v_2)$ if $(u_1,u_2)−(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, but I am not sure about the first claim above. How can one prove the first statement above? Is it maybe possible to show this directly by an example?

Comment: @DenilsonOrr: I am not claiming that and $$\sum_{a,b}f(a)g(b)=\sum_a f(a) \sum_b g(b)$$ is pretty trivial.

Comment: So you do not know if the following equation holds in general or not? $\sum_{\ell\in\mathbb{Z^2}} e^{-\vert x-\ell \vert^2}=\sum_{\ell\in\mathbb{Z^2}} e^{-\vert y-\ell \vert^2}$ for $\vert x\vert =\vert y\vert$

Comment: The given function depends on the fractional part of its arguments, it is very smooth and almost constant. The equality of such norms does not imply the equality of fractional parts, so such equality does not hold, in general. On the other hand, the given function is approximately constant at any point.